# Testing promises and sync functions that throw errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to build and test a function at the same time. Testing makes sense and I love it in theory, but when It comes down to it it always is a pain in the behind.

I have a function that takes a string and throws errors when something goes awry if all goes well it's going to return the original `text` argument and therefore a `truthy` value, if not it should be caught by the promise it's either in or itself as the promise.

This is the test / what I actually want to do (which doesn't work).

```
var main = require("./index.js")
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var mocha = require("mocha")
var chai = require("chai")
var chaiPromise = require("chai-as-promised")
chai.use(chaiPromise)

var shouldThrow = [
  "random", // invalid non-flag
  "--random", // invalid flag
  "--random string", //invalid flag
  "--wallpaper", // invalid flag w/ match
  "--notify", // invalid flag w/ match
  "wallpaper", // valid non-flag missing option(s) image
  "wallpaper image.jpg" // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621", // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/favicon.ico?12375621748379006621", // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/favicon.ico?12375621748379006621",  // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/favicon.ico?12375621748379006621",  // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper https://cdn.example.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/files/holstee_logo_2.png?4803", // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue",  // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue "+moment().subtract(1, "month").format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm"),  // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue "+moment().add(1, "month").format("YY-MM-DD-HH"), // invalid flag value
  "wallpaper --image http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621", // invalid flag value not https
  "wallpaper --image //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/favicon.ico?12375621748379006621", // invalid flag no protocol
  "wallpaper --image http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/favicon.ico?12375621748379006621",  // invalid flag value not https
  "wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/favicon.ico?12375621748379006621",  // invalid flag value not valid image
  "wallpaper --image https://cdn.example.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/files/holstee_logo_2.png?4803", // invalid flag image not found
  "wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue",  // invalid subflag queue missing value
  "wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue "+moment().subtract(1, "month").format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm"),  // invalid subflag queue date value is past
  "wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue "+moment().add(1, "month").format("YY-MM-DD-HH"), // invalid subflag queue date value format
  "--wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621", //no action non-flag
  "--wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue "+moment().add(1, "month").format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm"), //no action non-flag
  "notify", // valid non-flag missing option(s) message, open
  'notify --message "Hello world"', // valid flag missing params open
  'notify --open "https://www.holstee.com"', // valid flag missing params message
  'notify --message "Hello world" --open "http://www.holstee.com"', // invalid subflag value `open` should be https
  'notify --message "Hello world" --open "https://www.holstee.com" --queue', // invalid subflag queue missing value
  'notify --message "Hello world" --open "https://www.holstee.com" --queue '+moment().subtract(1, "month").format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm"), // invalid subflag queue date value is past
  'notify --message "Hello world" --open "https://www.holstee.com" --queue '+moment().add(1, "month").format("YY-MM-DD-HH"), // invalid subflag queue date value format
  '--notify --message "Hello world" --open "https://www.holstee.com"', //no action non-flag
  '--notify --message "Hello world" --open "https://www.holstee.com --queue "'+moment().add(1, "month").format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm"), //no action non-flag
]

var shouldNotThrow = [
  'notify --message "Hello world" --open "https://www.holstee.com"',
  'notify --message "Hello world" --open "https://www.holstee.com --queue "'+moment().add(1, "month").format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm"),
  "wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621",
  "wallpaper --image https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0031/5352/t/28/assets/holstee-calendar-2015-03-flow-desktop.jpg?12375621748379006621 --queue "+moment().add(1, "month").format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm"),
]

describe('Process Text', function(){
  return Promise.map(shouldThrow, function(option){
    it('throw error', function(){
      return main.processText(option).should.throw()
    })    
  })
  return Promise.map(shouldNotThrow, function(option){
    it('throw error', function(){
      return main.processText(option).should.not.throw()
    })    
  })
})
```

Here's a snapshot of the non-working* function I'm trying to test.

```
main.processText = function(text){
  var args = minimist(text.split(" "))
  var actions = _.keys(actionsFlags)
  var flags = _.chain(_.map(actionsFlags, _.keys)).flatten().uniq().value()
  var extraUnparsed = _.extra(actions, args._)
  var providedFlags = _.chain(args).keys().without("_").value()
  var extraParsed = _.extra(flags, providedFlags)
  var validActions = _.intersection(actions, args._)
  var requiredFlags = _.mapObject(actionsFlags, function(flags){
    return _.filterObject(flags, function(flag){
      return flag
    })
  })
  if(extraUnparsed.length) throw new Error("invalid unparsed argument(s): "+extraUnparsed.join(", "))
  if(extraParsed.length) throw new Error("invalid parsed argument(s): "+extraParsed.join(", "))
  if(validActions.length > 1) throw new Error("too many actions: "+validActions.join(", "))
  if(validActions.length == 0) throw new Error("no action: "+actions.join(", "))
  _.each(actions, function(action){
    var missingFlags = _.missing(_.keys(requiredFlags[action]), providedFlags)
    var extraFlags = _.extra(_.keys(requiredFlags[action]), providedFlags)
    if(_.contains(args._, action)){
      if(missingFlags.length) throw new Error(util.format("missing required flags for %s: %s", action, missingFlags.join(", ")))
      if(extraFlags.length) throw new Error(util.format("extra flags for %s: %s", action, extraFlags.join(", ")))
    }
  })
  return text
}
```

Note its not a promise and doesn't return any promises yet. One of the validation features I want is to check a if a url responds in a `200` status code, that's gonna be a `request` promise. If I update this function then does all of the function contents need to be nested within a `Promise.resolve(false).then()`? Perhaps the promise shouldn't be in this block of code and all `async` validation operations should exist somewhere else?

I don't know what I'm doing and I'm a little frustrated. I'm of course looking for some golden bullet or whatever that will make sense of all this.

**Ideally I could use some help on how to test this kind of function. If I make it into a promise later on I still want all my tests to work.**

---

Here's some example code of what I mean by sync functions and promises.

```
function syncFunction(value){
  if(!value) throw new Error("missing value")
  return value
}

function asyncFunction(url){
  return requestPromise(url)
}

// Both of these will throw errors the same way they will be caught by the promise then you can use `.catch` (in bluebird). 

Promise.resolve(false).then(function(){
  return syncFunction()
})

Promise.resolve(false).then(function(){
  return asyncFunction("http://404.com")
})
```

I want this to reflect the way that I test for errors and whether something `should` or `should not` throw an error in my test.

---

I left the promises out of it, it's a sync function and I'm testing like this.

```
describe('Process Text', function(){
  _.each(shouldThrow, function(option){
    it('throw error ('+option+')', function(){
      expect(function(){
        main.textValidation(option)
      }).to.throw()
    })
  })
  _.each(shouldNotThrow, function(option){
    it('not throw error ('+option+')', function(){
      expect(function(){
        main.textValidation(option)
      }).to.not.throw()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you please slim this question way , way down; into a more easily readible (less logic) which demonstrates the basic question you're asking?  You have multiple issues and I'm trying to figure out how to address this with a valid answer.  The main thing that's standing out at the moment is `Promise.each(shouldThrow, function(option){` makes no sense, the `.each` function accepts as the first arg a Function Iterator, not an array of strings.  If you scale this way down with just a couple lines of throw/not throw, and also minimize your implementation logic, it will be much easier to help

Comment: Great feedback @JustinMaat! I'm simply looking for a way to loop over the array strings asynchronously (using `.map` not `.each`, sorry) then be able to dictate whether a promise should or should not throw a error for a given test.

Comment: Ideally whatever the method is I'd be able to pass it a sync function that might throw errors or a promise that might throw errors and the interface for testing would be the same, because ideally it's wrapped in a promise already and it's going to be caught.

Comment: `Ideally whatever the method is I'd be able to pass it a sync function that might throw errors or a promise `  - what do you mean by pass it a sync function or promise?  Which method, processText?  It's currently not accepting a function or a promise.  You should consider slimming this down to just a small block of code to demonstrate what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to say - `If I make it into a promise later on I still want all my tests to work.` , promises just convert callback code to read in a synchronous style.  You're existing function is not taking a callback argument, so converting it to a promise doesn't make any sense.  I'll try to post an answer or gist if I can get the question a little better.  I think you're almost there though.

Comment: Added some more context, let me know if it helps or hurts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly recommend `npm install chai-as-promised`

```
return doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo");
```

https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised